# Wait for a long execution response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, httpresponse

I post an id to my server js, and it executes something that could take about a minute or more. I think the connection timeouts while waiting for the response and POSTs again. I want the client or browser to wait till the execution is done completely to return the response which is the result of the long execution.

I've looked online and I saw some questions regarding promise. I used promise and still it posted again. Are there any other solutions?

Code:

```
      $scope.imageget = function(target) {
          $http.post('/' + 'region/images', {under: id})
                 .then(function(docs)  {
                $scope.results = docs.data.results;
                var responss = docs.data.results;
                var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(responss);
                jobdetails = jsonresponse;
                console.log(jobdetails)
          });

        };
```

Code after promise:

```
      $scope.imageget = function(target) {
          var deferred= $q.defer();
          $timeout(function(){

          $http.post('/' + 'region/images', {under: id})
                 .then(function(docs)  {
                $scope.results = docs.data.results;
                var responss = docs.data.results;
                var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(responss);
                jobdetails = jsonresponse;
                console.log(jobdetails)
          });
          deferred.resolve();    
              }, 3000);  
          return deferred.promise;

        };
```

Comment: Using promises doesn't solve the connection timeout problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "it posts again"? And please don't only think, but *confirm* that the connection times out using the network panel of your developer tools.

Comment: like the request is sent again. When I respond after immediately sending the request it continues execution properly, but I want feedback of course to my client that depends on what is being executed.

Comment: You should consider handling your issue in another way. Your server can only handle a limited number of connexions at the same time. Your server should directly respond with an "OK", then handle it with a background service. The next step would be to do some pulling from your client (check status every x seconds), or using webSockets from your server to notify the client that the job has been finished.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe yes, I think this is the solution to at least give back progress.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout in $http config parameter (here I set it to three minutes).

```
  $scope.imageget = function(target) {
      $http.post('/' + 'region/images', 
             {under: id}, 
             {timeout: 180000})
             .then(function(docs)  {
            $scope.results = docs.data.results;
            var responss = docs.data.results;
            var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(responss);
            jobdetails = jsonresponse;
            console.log(jobdetails)
      });

    };
```

For more info on $http config, see [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). [This section](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) on config usage is particularly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs in your code

1. *Code after promise* waits 3000 ms and then executes the post.
2. The promise is returned emediately after the post reqeuest has been sent and does not wait until the post returns.

Waiting for 60 Seconds for a request should  not be a problem. So I sugest to have a look at your browsers (preferably Chrome ;-) ) network log and check whether it's really a timeout or if you get some kind of error code from the server.

Comment: Actually I checked, and found out that it remains pending, and re executes... Which rules out the time out. I cant find out where seems to be the problem, if I respond before the execution of the long task, the code runs perfectly, is I wait to respond after execution it restarts.